# "Your app appears to have a Canvas integration that redirects people away from Facebook."

Tags: facebook, canvas

I just got a developer notification alert saying:

> Your app appears to have a Canvas integration that redirects people away from Facebook. This violates Facebook Platform Policy 4.8: "Don’t build an app whose primary purpose is to redirect people off of Facebook." In order for us to consider your appeal, your app will need to stop redirecting users off of Facebook.

My app still appears to work. It doesn't actually do any redirect, or attempt to redirect away from Facebook. There are links to pages hosted on a separate domain (how else can I offer support pages?), but no redirects at all and all functionality works within canvas.

Where do I appeal? There is no information on how to contact or even deal with this message.

Comment: I responded to a very similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030999/im-getting-alert-this-violates-facebook-platform-policy-4-8-but-cant-see-why/28033102#28033102