# I'm getting alert: This violates Facebook Platform Policy 4.8 but can't see why?

Tags: facebook, alert

I'm getting constant alerts about the primary purpose of the app redirecting people off the Facebook platform. The entire app takes place within the community and even finishes by asking the user to return to the timeline. Would someone be able to shed light on the conflict. The app is a voting competition: http://bit.ly/UlsterWeddings

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The alert is below.

THE ALERT: Your app appears to have a Canvas integration that redirects people away from Facebook. This violates Facebook Platform Policy 4.8: "Don’t build an app whose primary purpose is to redirect people off of Facebook." In order for us to consider your appeal, your app will need to stop redirecting users off of Facebook.

Comment: Sorry wrong app, it was this app: http://a.pgtb.me/wngkxN

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

I've received this alert as well, as have many other developers who are discussing it in the Facebook Developer Community group on Facebook.

Just so we are all on the same page with respect to terminology, "canvas" refers to application web pages displayed in an iframe on facebook.com with the Facebook chrome/navigation elements surrounding the app's page content.  Facebook restricts some api methods to only being available on canvas pages, and prohibits unapproved advertising providers (read: Adsense) on canvas pages.

From what I've gathered, today Facebook deployed a new automated policy enforcement script which is why many apps are seeing this alert just now.  In typical Facebook fashion, no useful actionable information is provided.  The policy itself has not changed, but I was advised to review this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYcxyh5HQSI#t=94

The final example in the video is of a user clicking on a link from a post in their stream.  In the example, clicking the link takes the user to an off-canvas page.  I was told by a Facebook policy employee that this is specifically what my app is doing in violation of the policy.

My conclusion from this is that Facebook have ratcheted up enforcement and significantly tightened up their interpretation of the policy:  if your app allows the user to make a post while they are on a canvas page, any links in the post must go only to canvas pages.  That is my interpretation which seems to follow from what you see in the video, and from what a Facebook policy enforcement employee told me.

This is a huge departure from past interpretations of the policy.  I am guessing that thousands (tens of thousands?) of Facebook apps violate this policy as it is now being interpreted.  I for one shall be abandoning canvas and going back to a simple website with Facebook integration.